Continuously iterate through a dict
If we have a dict we can easily iterate through its values:
a = {'mon': 10, 'tue': 13, 'wed': 6, 'thu': 24, 'fri': 15}
for v in a:
    print(v)

I also have a nested loop like this:
while True:
    # some conditions to break the outer loop
    for v in a:
        # some conditions to break the inner loop
        print(v)

Every time it runs a cycle in the outer loop, it starts again from the "first" dict element (I'm aware dictionaries are not ordered, but if they are not modified the cycles should be the same).
Instead, I want it continues from the last key, and if it ends, starts again from the beginning.
Example:
1st outer cycle: 'mon', 'tue' (then breaks then inner cycle)
2nd outer cycle: 'wed' (then breaks then inner cycle)
3rd outer cycle: 'thu', 'fri', 'mon' (then breaks then inner cycle)
4th outer cycle: 'tue', 'wed' (then breaks then inner cycle)
breaks the outer cycle

My attempt was to save the last key and skip the previous ones, but is not straightforward and I have to restart the cycle if it ends before I have iterated through all keys.
Is there a simple way in Python to achieve this?

Dictionaries are ordered.

You don't iterate through the dict's values but through its keys.

If I understand your problem correctly, what you need is an infinitely iterable generator function:
def endless_generator(iterable):
    while True:
        for i in iterable:
            yield i

What this generator function does is simply to infinitely iterate through whatever iterable you pass to it.
You can use the generator function in your code like this
a = {'mon': 10, 'tue': 13, 'wed': 6, 'thu': 24, 'fri': 15}
g = endless_generator(a)
while True:
    # some conditions to break the outer loop
    for v in g:  # iterate through g instead of a
        # some conditions to break the inner loop
        print(v)


That is the way to do it if he keys never change - check itertools.cycle - but it essentially does the same as you do.

Yes, forgot that itertools.cycle exists for a moment. A minor caveat, itertools.cycle will attempt to copy the iterable itself to guard against the iterable being modified - as @jsbueno has indirectly pointed out. So if memory usage is important (which I believe is unlikely) or the iterable is extremely large (more likely scenario), you may want to avoid it.

Your code iterates over the keys of the dict, not it's values. This solutions shows how to iterate over the dict keys, like you showed in the example code. This should be sufficient for what you need, though there are probably faster solutions.
a = {'mon': 10, 'tue': 13, 'wed': 6, 'thu': 24, 'fri': 15}

# your start index
pos = 0
# get a list of the dict keys
a_keys = list(a) 
# get the length of the list
length = len(a_keys)

while True:
    # your outer break conditions
    while True:
        # your inner break conditions
        v = a_keys[pos]
        print(v)
        # increase position by one
        pos += 1
        # return to start when at the end
        if pos % length == 0: pos = 0         

If you actually want to iterate over the values instead, just replace v = a_keys[pos] with v = a[a_keys[pos]].

You can explicitly create and access an iterator.  For example:
a = {'mon': 10, 'tue': 13, 'wed': 6, 'thu': 24, 'fri': 15}

t = iter(a)
active = True
while active:
    while True:
        try:
            v = next(t)
        except StopIteration:
            print("done")
            active = False
            break
        print(v)
        # The following condition can be anything you want
        if v == 'wed':
            print("breaking")
            break

In this example, the inner loop breaks when 'wed' is encountered, but of course this can be changed to any desired condition.
Calling next(t) will give you the next value of the iterator.  When the end is reached, a StopIteration exception is raised.  The above code fragment produces:
mon
tue
wed
breaking
thu
fri
done

It basically allows the iterator to run independently from the outer loop.
If you want to restart the iterator from the beginning when the end is reached, you can just create a new iterator with t = iter(a) when the end is reached.  In that case, you don't need the active flag.  You can just follow it with v = next(a).  If the dictionary is empty, this will raise a StopIteration exception, so you'd need to decide what you want to do if that happens.
